# Racket web server cannot response get parameter

Tags: racket

I've tried to response what we got from the get parameter `name`, but it always response

> name:&req;&name;

With the url

> http://localhost:8080/?name=stcoder

The source code would be

```
(require web-server/servlet
         web-server/servlet-env
         web-server/http/bindings)

(define (lookup-binding req id)
  (if (exists-binding? id (request-bindings req))
      (extract-binding/single id (request-bindings req))
      #f))


(provide/contract (my-app (request? . -> . response?)))

(define (my-app req)
  (response/xexpr
   '(html (head (title "Wizard!"))
          (body (p "name:" ,(lookup-binding req 'name))))))

(serve/servlet my-app
               #:launch-browser? #f
               #:quit? #f
               #:listen-ip #f
               #:port 8080
               #:servlet-path "/")
```

Comment: You’re using `unquote` (aka comma) without `quasiquote` (aka backtick). Replace `'(html ...)` with `\`(html ...)`.